# Codeigniter + Doctrine and too many mysql connections

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, doctrine

I am running a large scale website with Codeigniter and Doctrine using RDS master/slave DBs, but for some reason I keep running into a Doctrine error of `too many mysql hosts` issue. The error tells me to flush the mysql hosts and it will fix the issue, and it does, but my question is, is anyone else experiencing this issue? If so, how are you getting around it so that it doesn't continually happen?

Comment: Yes, we are experiencing the same issue using Zend Framework, Doctrine and RDS. Did the default database config in CodeIgniter help, or was the issue resolved in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

You say in your post title too many mysql connections, but in your question you say too many mysql hosts? If it is down to too many connections, then changing the following CodeIgniter default in the database config file might help:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

It defaults to true, meaning CodeIgniter uses persistent connections - which can be a problem depending on how many simultaneous visitors you have and also your webhost's mysql configuration.